# Python magical main() signature like Perl 6

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, raku, magic-methods, method-signature

Does python have any way to easily and quickly make CLI utilities without lots of argument parsing boilerplate?

In Perl 6, the signature for the `MAIN` sub [automagically parses command line arguments.](http://perlgeek.de/blog-en/perl-5-to-6/14-main-sub.html)

Is there any way to do something similar in Python without lots of boilerplate? If there is not, what would be the best way to do it? I'm thinking a function decorator that will perform some introspection and do the right thing. If there's nothing already like it, I'm thinking something like what I have below. Is this a good idea?

```
@MagicMain
def main(one, two=None, *args, **kwargs):
    print one # Either --one or first non-dash argument
    print two # Optional --arg with default value (None)
    print args # Any other non-dash arguments
    print kwargs # Any other --arguments

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: The `MAIN` sub is **much** more powerful than that blog post shows. As an example you can have multiple `MAIN` subroutines that take different arguments. See [Synopsis 06](http://perlcabal.org/syn/S06.html#Declaring_a_MAIN_subroutine "Declaring a MAIN subroutine") for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Baker](http://bitbucket.org/mchaput/baker/wiki/Home) library contains some convenient decorators to "automagically" create arg parsers from method signatures.

For example:

```
@baker.command
def test(start, end=None, sortby="time"):
  print "start=", start, "end=", end, "sort=", sortby

$ script.py --sortby name 1
start= 1 end= sortby= name
```

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I imagined. I'll look into it and leave a green cookie for you when I do :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you consider to be parsing boilerplate. The 'current' approach is to use the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) system for python. The older system is [getopt](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html).

Comment: `argparse` seems like it could be good under the hood of a decorator like I describe... It could remove all the `parser.add_argument` boilerplate.

Answer (score 2):

Simon Willison's [`optfunc`](http://github.com/simonw/optfunc) module tries to provide the functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The `opterator` module handles this.

https://github.com/buchuki/opterator

Answer (score 0):

Python has the [getopts](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html) module for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I came across the [begins](http://begins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) project for decorating and simplifying command line handling.

It seems to offer a lot of the same functions you are looking for.